# How do I detect when the splitter bar is moved? Or when the panes are being resized?

Tags: javascript, sapui5

Here is a link to a plunk with a Responsive Splitter: https://embed.plnkr.co/0yo35xOiSmF5eG6R?show=V.view.xml,preview.

How do I detect when the splitter bar between the panes is being moved and thus resized? `window.resize()` only works for the window and zooming in/zooming out.

Comment: In UI5 1.92, a [`resize` event was added to `sap.ui.layout.PaneContainer`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68175162/5846045) which will also notify when the bar from the `ResponsiveSplitter` has moved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ResponsiveSplitter` does not have any `resize` event. You can implement your own handler using jQuery and DOM events. [Here is an example on Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/WqfEE1X7badOZLdbDYV9?p=preview).

Controller:

```
sap.ui.define([
    "sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller"
], function (Controller) {
    "use strict";

    return Controller.extend("demo.V", {

        _paneWidths: [],

        onInit: function() {
            this._resizeHandler = this.onSplitterResize.bind(this);

            document.addEventListener("touchend", this._resizeHandler);
            document.addEventListener("mouseup", this._resizeHandler);
        },

        onExit: function() {
            document.removeEventListener("touchend", this._resizeHandler);
            document.removeEventListener("mouseup", this._resizeHandler);
        },

        onSplitterResize: function() {
            var resized = false;
            var panes = this.getView().byId("paneContainer").getPanes();
            for (var index = 0; index < panes.length; index++) {
                var paneWidth = $(panes[index].getContent().getDomRef()).parent().css("width");
                if (paneWidth !== this._paneWidths[index]) {
                    this._paneWidths[index] = paneWidth;
                    resized = true;
                }
            }

            if (resized) {
                // here goes your resize logic
            }
        }

    });
});
```

Comment: Since 1.92, the `resize` event can be used in `sap.ui.layout.PaneContainer`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68175162/5846045

Answer (score 1):

You could use the sap.ui.layout.Splitter and the [Resize Event](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#/api/sap.ui.layout.Splitter/events/resize).

Answer (score 0):

- `sap/ui/layout/Splitter` comes with the [event `resize`](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#/api/sap.ui.layout.Splitter/events/resize):

  ```xml
  <layout:Splitter resize=".onPaneResize" />
  ```
- **Since v1.92:** `sap/ui/layout/PaneContainer`, which is often used within `sap/ui/layout/ResponsiveSplitter`, has also the [`resize` event](https://openui5nightly.hana.ondemand.com/api/sap.ui.layout.PaneContainer#events/Events):

  ```xml
  <layout:ResponsiveSplitter>
    <layout:PaneContainer resize=".onPaneResize" /> <!-- Since 1.92 -->
  ```

The Demo Kit [sample of `ResponsiveSplitter`](https://openui5nightly.hana.ondemand.com/entity/sap.ui.layout.ResponsiveSplitter/sample/sap.ui.layout.sample.ResponsiveSplitter) is updated accordingly. If you move the bar, the app reports the sizes accordingly.